# Angular material open menu in a single click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have 2 angular material icons with in one component, each with a menu - for example *menu1* and *menu2*. When I click the *menu1* icon it will open the *menu1* list. Then, when I click the *menu2* icon I need to close the *menu1* list and open *menu2*. But now I need to do two clicks to do this activity. First click closes the *menu1* and only second click opens the *menu2*. How can I implement one-click open  of the second menu using `mat-menu`?

Menu1 html

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
    <span>Redial</span>
  </button>
</mat-menu>
```

Menu2 html

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu2="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
        <span>Redial</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Example present [angular material sample](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples). My question is how open and close menu in a single short?

Answer (score 0):

Menu1 html

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu (closed)="menuOneClosed()" #menu1="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
        <span>Redial</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Menu2 html

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
      <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu2="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
        <span>Redial</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

Component instance

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) menu2: MatMenuTrigger;

menuOneClosed(){
    this.meu2.openMenu();
}
```

Comment: Hi Bro thanks for your reply,  in your answer when we click on the menu1,  menu2 will open right? i don't want that behavior. menu2 should be open when we click on menu2 and viz versa in single click.